# Substitute second occurence on line

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a list of files:

```
./a.temp.txt     ./a.temp.txt
./a/b.temp.txt   ./a/b.temp.txt
./a/b/c.temp.txt ./a/b/c.temp.txt
```

And I want to remove the `temp.` on each line, but only the **second occurence**, thus, the file should look like:

```
./a.temp.txt     ./a.txt
./a/b.temp.txt   ./a/b.txt
./a/b/c.temp.txt ./a/b/c.txt
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Is it possible that there will be a third or fourth occurrence on any line? Do these have to remain intact?

Comment: My case was to match old filename to new filename, so only 2 occurrences will be on each line. And only the second one should change.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general you can match the Nth occurrence of something
using `\zs` and `\{N}`. There's an example given at `:help \zs`.

In your case the command would be:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}\zstemp\.\)\{2}//
```

Comment: with the verymagic flag you can reduce the regex: `%s/\v(.{-}\zstemp.){2}//`

Answer (score 14):

This is much easier done with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.temp\././2'
```

With Vim you need non-greedy matching, and it isn't easy to extend the method to replacing the 3rd, 4th, etc. occurrence of `temp`.  But it can be done if you insist:

```
:%s/\.temp\..\{-}\.\zstemp\.//
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the sed solution, do you think it's possible to apply this on each line ?

Comment: @nobe4 Not sure what you mean by that.  `sed` applies scripts to each line of input in turn.

Comment: yes, but you can pass lines into external program and get back the result.

Comment: You mean from Vim?  Sure, you can pipe lines to `sed` just as you can pipe them to any other program.  F.i.: `:%!sed 's/\.temp\././2'`.  `sed` in UNIX-friendly, it reads input from `stdin` and writes results to `stdout`.

Answer (score 12):

This solution is similar to TessellatingHeckler's but is more easily adapted to whatever pattern has to be deleted.

```
:g/temp\./normal 2ngnd
```

Here's how it works:

1. `:g/temp\./` for every line matching "temp."
2. `normal` execute the following in normal mode

   3. `2n` find the second ocurrence of the pattern
   4. `gn` select it
   5. `d` and delete it.

This will work for whatever pattern is given to `:g`.
`normal` may be abbreviated to `norm`.
`gnd` is equivalent to `dgn`.
*Edit: In fact `2ngnd` is equivalent to `d2gn`.*

See [the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) for more examples of the global command.

Comment: TIL! This is my new favorite editing method. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this with a lookbehind.

```
:%s/\(temp\..*\)\@<=temp\.//
```

If you want to remove *ALL* occurrences after the first, you can append the `g` flag at the end.

`\(\)\@<=` Will search for any pattern between `\(` and `\)` but will not add the found text to the match.

See `:h \@<=` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a macro as @Meshpi already suggested. But, this is another way you can accomplish the same thing.

```
02/temp^Mdwx+
```

> 0 - Go to the starting of a line
>
> 2/temp - Search for temp and go to the second occurance
>
> ^M - This is just pressing the Enter key
>
> dw - delete the word (temp)
>
> x - delete the '.'
>
> + - Go to the beginning of the next line

And, then you can just repeat it till the end. And, there will be a lot more ways to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

In Vim, you can define the column before/at/after which you want your matching to happen with `:help \%c`:

```
:%s/\%>17c\.temp/g
```

This will get rid of every `.temp` found after column 17 of every line in the current buffer.

---

Note 1: the `/g` is not necessary with your sample.

Note 2: I use that handy feature very often with [qmv](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/). Recommended!

Comment: Neat, I was thinking of making a plugin, but this is nice!

Comment: Vim already does so many things…

Comment: Sure, but I was not aware of this tool. And a little bit of scripting is always fun!

Comment: @nobe4 If you care about this kind of things, see also `vidir` and `vipe` from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually pretty simple. To match the second temp, allow anything followed by "temp" followed by anything, then look for temp again.

```
%s/.*temp.*\zstemp\.
```

The `\zs` means "Start the selection here" so that the first part of the match (everything before the second temp) isn't removed. It's actually an extremely useful feature that I just learned about! Without it, the regex would have to look like this:

```
:%s/\(.*temp.*\)temp\./\1
```

Comment: If there are more than two `temp` on a line your recipe deletes the last one, rather than the second.  Blame the greed. :)

Comment: Yes, this is greedy, and so it deletes the last one. However, OP said `My case was to match old filename to new filename, so only 2 occurrences will be on each line. And only the second one should change`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of regex, I'd go with a command which does:

- Jump to end of line
- Search backwards for `temp`
- Delete 5 characters

and run it on every line:

```
:g//normal $?temp^[5x
```

NB. `^[` is special and represents pressing the Escape key; you type it with: `Ctrl-q <Esc>`

---

But a regex option, which I don't think has been suggested yet, is to match `temp.` followed by anything except a `.`, anchored to the end of the line.

```
:%s/temp\.\([^.]\+\)$/\1/
```

Which will match `temp.txt` at the end of a line and replace it with just the `txt` bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a macro with the cursor starting at the top left.
`qq4f.dfpq`

Then I'd select the rest of the lines using `V` and run the macro on those lines with `:'<,'>norm!@q`

This will only work if the text format stays the same in relation to the number of dots before the second temp.

Comment: To make your macro more robust, you should use a search and `n` instead of `4f.` because if a filename has more dots, your macro could fail or delete stuff which shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing preventing you from using *two regexes* instead of just one, i.e. change the first occurrence and then swap the columns:

```
:%s/\.temp//|%s/^\(\S\+\)\(\s\+\)\(\S\+\)/\3\2\1/
```

Might not be extra clever but I find it very readable.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt

```
:%norm 4ftdwx

:%norm ......... execute in normal mode over the whole file  
4ft ............ the 4th t matches the start of the second temp
dw ............. deletes the current word
x .............. deletes the dot
```