# How to make substituition of pattern if it occurs after different pattern?

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to have a regular expression that replace:

```
"foo" "bar" Is "hello" "world" "!"
```

by:

```
"foo" "bar" Is "hello world !"
```

I have tried `:%s/Is\(\s*"\([^"]*\)"\)*/Is "\2\4\6"/`

But it seems that `\2` is the last capture of the second group (`!`) and it returns:

```
Is "!"
```

Is there a way to do that in Vim?

Comment: This works for your example: `:s/" "/ /g`

Comment: Indeed but my real problem is actually slightly different I want to do the replacement only if the list of quoted string is prefixed by a the keyword: Is. I have updated the question to encompass its full complexity.

Comment: I don't see from the updated example what the problem is... From your comment, it sounds like you want to apply a substitution command only on lines that begin with the word 'Is'. In that case, you can use the following: `:g/^Is/s/" "/ /g`

Comment: Good idea, but what is I would have "foo" "bar" is "hello" "world" "!" and only want the conversion applied on the second part: "hello" "world" "!"?

Comment: Ah ok, you should put this example in your question (it's different than what you have there now). I can't think of an easy way at the moment - but there are people better at this than me :) Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599286/find-and-replace-only-part-of-a-single-line-in-vim) and [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/substitute-second-occurence-on-line)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mattb](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/31858/mattb) pointed correctly the answer is:

`:s/\(is.*\)\@<="\s\+"/ /g`

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this task is to use the `:s` regexp to skip the initial part (`Is` , in your case) and then use the [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function to make multiple substitutions in the replacement.

In the pattern, you can use the [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) marker to start matching only after the part you want to skip (so you don't need to take care of repeating the `Is`  in your replacement.)

In the replacement, you can use [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) to introduce a Vimscript expression (which will allow you to call the `substitute()` function), and then you can use [`submatch(0)`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#submatch%28%29) to access the contents of the pattern that matched the `:s` command (which is where you want the substitutions to happen.)

Putting it all together:

```
:s/Is \zs.*/\=substitute(submatch(0), '"\s\+"', ' ', 'g')/
```

Comment: Thanks. It works too.